# Springframework - property or field cannot be found on null

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am working on a project and keep getting an error.

`<span style="font-style: italic;" th:text="${user != null} ? ${#strings.toUpperCase(user.username)} : 'user is null'"></span>`

```
EL1007E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on null
```

I'm new to thyemeleaf and spring so still learning so not sure what you would need to help figure out the issue so I will update when I know what I need to provide.

Header HTML where login/New user modal is

```html
<body>
  <div th:fragment="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand active" href="https://inplaydesign.com/index.html">d|b</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="https://blog.inplaydesign.com">blog</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/gallery/gallery.html">gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">shop</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/faq/faq.html">f.a.q.</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/contact/contact.html">contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Shopping Cart
     </button>
          <button sec:authorize="isAnonymous()" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#accountAccess">
      <i class="fa fa-id-card"></i> Account
     </button>
          <a sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" th:href="@{/myProfile}">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">
       <i class="fa fa-id-card"></i> Account
      </button>
          </a>
          <a sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" th:href="@{/logout}">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">
       <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> log-out
      </button>
          </a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- Account modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="accountAccess" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Account Login and Creation
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
              <li class="nav-item" th:classappend="${classActiveNewAccount}? 'active'">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-1" role="tab">Sign up</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item" th:classappend="${classActiveLogin}? 'active'">
                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-2" role="tab">User Login</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item" th:classappend="${classActiveForgetPassword}? 'active'">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-3" role="tab">Forgot Password</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" style="margin-top: 10px;">
              <!-- New User -->
              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-1" role="tabpanel" th:classappend="${classActiveNewAccount}? 'in active'">
                <form th:action="@{/newUser}" method="post">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="email">Email Address</label>&nbsp;
                      <div class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${emailExists}">"Email already exists"</div>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="NewUsername">Username</label>&nbsp;
                      <div class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${usernameExists}">"Username already exists"</div>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newUsername" name="NewUsername" tabindex="0" placeholder="Enter Username" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">
           <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Reset
          </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">
           <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Create New Account
          </button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>

              <!-- login -->
              <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab-2" role="tabpanel" th:classappend="${classActiveLogin}? 'active'">
                <div class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${param.error != null}">
                  <small>Please check your credentials and try again.</small>
                </div>
                <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="username">Username</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="password">Password</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">
           <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Log-In
          </button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>

              <!-- Forgot password -->
              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-3" role="tabpanel" th:classappend="${classActiveForgetPassword}? 'in active'">
                <div th:if="${emailNotExist}" class="alert alert-danger">Email does not exist</div>
                <div th:if="${forgetPasswordEmailSent}" class="alert alert-success">Please check your email for password reset token.</div>
                <form action="">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="recoverEmail">User Email</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="recoverEmail" placeholder="Enter Recovery Email" name="email" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">
           <i class="fa fa-external-link-square"></i> Submit
          </button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div th:fragment="body-bottom-scripts">
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </div>
</body>
```

```js
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.digitalblasphemy.domain.User;
import com.digitalblasphemy.domain.security.PasswordResetToken;
import com.digitalblasphemy.domain.security.Role;
import com.digitalblasphemy.domain.security.UserRole;
import com.digitalblasphemy.service.UserService;
import com.digitalblasphemy.service.impl.UserSecurityService;
import com.digitalblasphemy.utility.MailConstructor;
import com.digitalblasphemy.utility.SecurityUtility;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

  @Autowired
  private JavaMailSender mailSender;

  @Autowired
  private MailConstructor mailConstructor;

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  @Autowired
  private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String index() {
    return "index";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/myAccount")
  public String myAccount() {
    return "myAccount";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/login")
  public String login(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("classActiveLogin", true);
    return "myProfile";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/forgetPassword")
  public String forgetPassword(
    HttpServletRequest request,
    @ModelAttribute("email") String email,
    Model model
  ) {
    model.addAttribute("classActiveForgetPassword", true);
    User user = userService.findByEmail(email);

    if (user == null) {
      model.addAttribute("emailNotExist", true);
      return "index";
    }

    String password = SecurityUtility.randomPassword();

    String encryptedPassword = SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder().encode(password);
    user.setPassword(encryptedPassword);

    userService.save(user);

    String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    userService.createPasswordResetTokenForUser(user, token);

    String appUrl = "http://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath();

    SimpleMailMessage newEmail = mailConstructor.constructResetTokenEmail(appUrl, request.getLocale(), token, user, password);

    mailSender.send(newEmail);

    model.addAttribute("forgetPasswordEmailSent", "true");

    return "index";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/newUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String newUserPost(
    HttpServletRequest request,
    @ModelAttribute("email") String userEmail,
    @ModelAttribute("username") String username,
    Model model
  ) throws Exception {
    model.addAttribute("classActiveNewAccount", true);
    model.addAttribute("email", userEmail);
    model.addAttribute("username", username);

    if (userService.findByUsername(username) != null) {
      model.addAttribute("usernameExists", true);

      return "index";
    }

    if (userService.findByEmail(userEmail) != null) {
      model.addAttribute("emailExists", true);

      return "index";
    }

    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername(username);;
    user.setEmail(userEmail);

    String password = SecurityUtility.randomPassword();

    String encryptedPassword = SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder().encode(password);
    user.setPassword(encryptedPassword);

    Role role = new Role();
    role.setRoleId(1);
    role.setName("ROLE_USER");
    Set < UserRole > userRoles = new HashSet < > ();
    userRoles.add(new UserRole(user, role));
    userService.createUser(user, userRoles);

    String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    userService.createPasswordResetTokenForUser(user, token);

    String appUrl = "http://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath();

    SimpleMailMessage email = mailConstructor.constructResetTokenEmail(appUrl, request.getLocale(), token, user, password);

    mailSender.send(email);

    model.addAttribute("emailSent", "true");

    return "myAccount";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/newUser")
  public String newUser(
    Locale locale,
    @RequestParam("token") String token,
    Model model) {

    PasswordResetToken passToken = userService.getPasswordResetToken(token);

    if (passToken == null) {
      String message = "Invalid Token.";
      model.addAttribute("message", message);
      return "redirect:/badRequest";
    }

    User user = passToken.getUser();
    String username = user.getUsername();

    UserDetails userDetails = userSecurityService.loadUserByUsername(username);

    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    model.addAttribute("user", user);

    model.addAttribute("classActiveEdit", true);
    return "myProfile"; //possibly change to index page
  }
}
```

I have this in my Application.java file to create a user for testing purposes.

```js
@Override
public void run(String...args) throws Exception {
  User user1 = new User();
  user1.setFirstName("Kyle");
  user1.setLastName("Drew");
  user1.setUsername("kd");
  user1.setPassword(SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder().encode("p"));
  user1.setEmail("kd@me.com");
  Set < UserRole > userRoles = new HashSet < > ();
  Role role1 = new Role();
  role1.setRoleId(1);
  role1.setName("ROLE_USER");
  userRoles.add(new UserRole(user1, role1));

  userService.createUser(user1, userRoles);
}
```

Here is a picture of the variables after debugging.

[image: variables]

Comment: It's null so it can't render it. Create a condition that if it's null, make username some placeholder text

Comment: There's no variable named `user` in the template context. Post the Spring MVC controller method that's responsible for this page.

Comment: added the homecontroller

Comment: Looks like the `user` object you add into your model is `null`, so when you try and render `user.username` you get your first error. Try stepping through your controller in your debugger to see what the value of `user` is.

Comment: When I start up the server and it connects to the database in mysql, I get the confirmation `User kd already Exists. Nothing will be done.`

Comment: added a picture of the variables that i have when the breakpoint is reached and the exception is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  In the SecurityConfig.Java file I did not have the .loginPage pointing to the correct location which was creating the exception.

```js
http
  .csrf().disable().cors().disable()
  .formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error").defaultSuccessUrl("/")
  .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
  .and()
  .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
  .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout").deleteCookies("remember-me").permitAll()
  .and()
  .rememberMe();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid this exception by checking if the `user` is null.

```
<span style="font-style: italic;" th:text="${user != null} ? ${#strings.toUpperCase(user.username)} : 'user is null'"></span>
```

But, better approach will be to make sure that `user` won't be added into model without being initialized.

Comment: The token i create I can access the profile page fine and the user name shows up where its supposed to when I use the token.  But when I try the login using the credentials.  I get the exception `Property or field 'id' cannot be found on null`.  I would ask the instructor but he doesn't answer questions apparently if the page of questions with no response from him on udemy is any indication.

Comment: still getting the exception.  I did a debugger and added the variables i was getting when the breakpoint was reached.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your user object is not null before you putting into the model

Comment: explain to me where based on the information i have provided that you're seeing something = null.  the only thing that should be = null is if ther username or email already exists.

Comment: There's what _should_ be `null` and your error message `field username cannot be found *on null*` that suggests otherwise. You can settle it easily enough in your debugger.

Comment: thats great but i'm not sure exactly what i'm looking at.  Any assistance in finding good documentation on what I should be looking for?  As I said I"m new to this language and the instructor teaches the class like a youtube tutorial (ie doesn't explain anything and what he does explain is so vague that all it does is cause frustration).

Comment: Put a breakpoint wherever you add the user into your model in your controller, eg. `model.addAttribute("user", user);`. Inspect the value of `user` and see whether it's `null`.

Comment: Well I added the breakpoint in eclipse and it pointed me to `throw new SpelEvaluationException(SpelMessage.PROPERTY_OR_FIELD_NOT_READABLE_ON_NULL, name);` 
in the daemon thread the last item there is `owns: NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper (id=122)` whatever that means